# How to get specific area boundaries on a map?

Tags: polygon

I want to get specific area boundaries highlighted on the map or by coordinates. I tried to search on google maps with this structure (district, city, country), sometimes it works and give me the area boundaries like this :

[image]

and sometimes it shows the area but without highlighted boundaries. How can I do it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to have these areas in a gis environment.

There are multiple ways I do this (for the Netherlands).

1. You can manually create polygons by using google maps areas (from
   your picture)
2. Find data about the area boundaries. For the Netherlands you can
       find them here http://www.imergis.nl/asp/47.asp
   a quick google search for you area led me here https://www.citypopulation.de/php/egypt-greatercairo.php